# Salesforce Field goes to true when a case enters a queue

Tags: salesforce

It seems like a silly question but I have a custom field on an object in salesforce that is a checkbox and I want to automatically go to true when a case enter a queue how can I do that.

Comment: Please share your code!

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can accomplish this without code. I would explore Process Builder in the setup UI to accomplish this. You are able to set decision criteria and then update the record.